# Cast the return value of a function that returns a floating point type

Tags: c, function, floating-point

I have difficulty understanding the article [Cast the return value of a function that returns a floating point type](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP37-C.+Cast+the+return+value+of+a+function+that+returns+a+floating+point+type)

(1) In

> Conversion as if by assignment to the type of the function is required if the return expression has a different type than the function, but not if the return expression has a wider value only because of wide evaluation.

What is "wide evaluation"? What does it try to say?

(2） in the example

```
float f(float x) {  
  return x * 0.1f;  
}  

float g(float x) {  
  return x * 0.1;  
}
```

Why "Function f is allowed to return a value wider than float, but function g (which uses the wider constant) is not"?

In f(), x and 0.1f are both float type so I think x * 0.1f is also float type? In g(), 0.1 is probably regarded as double, so x * 0.1 is double?

(3) What's the moralities of the article?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: @JonH: I highly doubt secured coding restrictions are being done as homework....  Sounds like trying to get up to speed for a job.

Comment: This does not smell like homework. Who in the right mind would teach crazy peculiarities of C language in a classroom? This is what real world is for!

Comment: It's not homework. I am trying to figure out the Dos and Don'ts when using floating point.

Answer (score 2):

Function g returns type float which is a 32 bit value. 0.1 is interpreted as a double which means that the expression x * 0.1 returns a double. A double is a 64 bit value which will cause a narrowing conversion in order to be returned as a float. x can safely be converted to a double because that is a widening conversion from float to double.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) In
>
> ```
> Conversion as if by assignment to the type of the function is required
> ```
>
> if the return expression has a
>   different type than the function, but
>   not if the return expression has a
>   wider value only because of wide
>   evaluation.
>
> What is "wide evaluation"? What does
>   it try to say?

If you declare a byte variable or constant, it may actually be stored as DWORD on 32-bit platform. Byte arithmetics may also be implemented as 32-bit arithmetics (wide evaluation). It does not cause problems for integer types.

> (2） in the example
>
> float f(float x) {     return x *
>   0.1f;   }
>
> float g(float x) {     return x * 0.1;
>   }
>
> Why "Function f is allowed to return a
>   value wider than float, but function g
>   (which uses the wider constant) is
>   not"?

That is what the current C standard says: 0.1f may be stored in a wider format (than float), x * 0.1f may also be evaluated in a wider format, and return operator is not required to perform conversion to float and may return the result "as is". With the g function, the return operator is required to perform a conversion from double to float.

> In f(), x and 0.1f are both float type
>   so I think x * 0.1f is also float
>   type? In g(), 0.1 is probably regarded
>   as double, so x * 0.1 is double?

Yes, that is right for all 32-bit compilers (at least I think so :) ). But the article is dealing with the issue in general.

> (3) What's the moralities of the
>   article?

The C standard is a hard thing to learn :)